# Preloading images

Tags: css, joomla

i've a navigation bar like the one below..for each

it changes the background color on mouseover and mouseout and there is a lag to load those images which looks awful :(
i wanna know how to preload those images so that i can save that lag time and make it work smoothly..

```
<ul class="nav">
 <li class="Today"><a href="/" class="Active"/></li>
 <li class="Hot"><a href="/hot" class=""/></li>
 <li class="New"><a href="/new" class=""/></li>
 <li class="Categoies"><a href="/cat" class=""/></li>
 <li class="Terms"><a href="/terms" class=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

the css to display on **mouseout** event :

```
#nav .Today a {
-moz-background-clip:border;
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
-moz-background-origin:padding;
background:transparent url(../images/today.png) no-repeat scroll left top;
border:0 none;
height:25px;
text-decoration:none;
width:98px;
}
```

the css to display on **mouseover** event

```
#nav .Today .Active {
-moz-background-clip:border;
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
-moz-background-origin:padding;
background:transparent url(../images/today-over.png) no-repeat scroll left top;
border:0 none;
height:25px;
text-decoration:none;
width:98px;
}
```

BTW, this is done in joomla..
thankx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for ur replies guys..
i found a way to reload all the images using jquery here:
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_automatically_preload_images_from_css_with_jquery/

Answer (score 7):

I would do some research into CSS sprites, it will negate the need to preload your images and it will make your page load times go much faster. [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) has a good article on CSS sprites.

If you really wanted to preload that one image you can create a really tiny pixel with a background of the image you wanted to hover over, it's not a very elegant solution but it would do the job.

```
#preload
{
    background-image:url(../images/today-over.png);
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

And then on your page:

```
<div id="preload"></div>
```

Comment: i could have use css but since it's in joomla i'm hesitating..is there any other wa like jquery or something?

Comment: You should still be able to do all that in Joomla. You can just edit your template's CSS file to style it.

Answer (score 3):

As Sam152 said, you should use CSS sprites. This will solve your problem as well as cutting down on HTTP requests.

The simple way is instead of `today.png` and `today-over.png` put them into one image, one above the other, that is 98px by 50px. Then use this CSS:

```
#nav .Today a {
    background: transparent url(../images/today.png) no-repeat scroll left top;
}
#nav .Today .Active {
    background-position: left bottom;
}
```

Note: I removed the other styles to keep this looking clean, but keep those in your code!

The more advanced, and generally better, way is to merge *all* the menu images into one, so you only have one image to load. You'd have a 490x50 image, and CSS like this:

```
#nav .Today a {
    background: transparent url(../images/today.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
}
#nav .Today a.Active {
    background-position: 0 -25px;
}
#nav .Hot a {
    background: transparent url(../images/hot.png) no-repeat scroll -98px 0;
}
#nav .Hot a.Active {
    background-position: -98px -25px;
}
```

...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could make your browser preload those images, if you would place them on a hidden div on your page, like this:

`<div style="display:none;"> ... the images ... </div>`